# Geographic Hierarchies in a OLAP Cube / Data Warehouse

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, spatial, olap, design-pattern

1. Are the following geographic hierarchies correct?
2. Do any US/Canadian area codes cross state/province lines?
3. Do any US/Canadian counties cross state/province lines?
4. Are there countries with counties but no principal country divisions (states/provinces)?

## Zip / Postal Codes

### US Style

Continent > Country > State/Province > Postal/Zip

### UK Style

Continent > Country > Postal Code

## Towns / Cities

### US Style

Continent > Country > State/Province > City

### UK Style

Continent > Country > City

## Area Codes

### US Style

Continent > Country > State/Province > Area Code

### UK Style

Continent > Country > Area Code

## Counties

### US Style

Continent > Country > State/Province > County

### UK Style

Continent > Country > County

Comment: I've been out of the postal game for a few years but I do believe there were US postal codes that crossed state boundaries. Sorry I can't be more specific on that front, I only have a hazy recollection of the incident

Comment: Maybe you'd get better traction at [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @swasheck  should I delete this question here, or should I post on both? thx

Comment: I don't know how U.S. post codes work but UK post codes go something like 'Area' (SW), 'District' (SW20), 'Sector' (SW20 8), 'Postcode' (SW20 8RX).  I don't think it's directly related to counties.

Answer (score 1):

To answer at least some of this:

2. Area codes do cross state boundaries in rare cases. There is a tiny bit of the Oregon 541 area code that is shared with California:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_541_and_458

3. Zip codes do very rarely cross state boundaries, or have really odd zip code assignments compared to their geographical assignments. One example being 65733 in Arkansas and Missouri, where a few remote places are served by the 65733 Missouri Zip code:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code#Secondary_regional_prefixes_.28123xx.29_and_local_ZIP_codes_.2812345.29

4. New Zealand used to have only counties, when they abolished provinces in the 1800's, and now a lot of them have merged into districts. Denmark also changed from counties to regions as well, without any provinces. Norway and Hungary are two more examples of a hop from country to county. There's a lot of fascinating pages on Wikipedia regarding counties and other administrative divisions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County

1. There are certainly odd cases that would be hard to fit into the hierarchies you've outlined above. China, for example, has prefectural level cities that are below a province and above a county in their administrative division hierarchy. I'm not sure how much effort you would want to go through to make these generic by country, though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_China

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_administrative_divisions_by_country

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division

Hope that helps answer your question. =)

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you are really looking for is [ragged hierarchies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365406.aspx)

> A ragged hierarchy is a user-defined hierarchy that has an uneven
>   number of levels. Common examples include an organizational chart
>   where a high-level manager has both departmental managers and
>   non-managers as direct reports, or geographic hierarchies composed of
>   Country-Region-City, where some cities lack a parent State or
>   Province, such as Washington D.C., Vatican City, or New Delhi.

There isn't much to say about that with the lack of detail in your question except what the docs say but that would allow you to have a single dimension/hierarchy supporting all combinations in some sort of way.